# Mule http proxy require double slashes (Failed to route event via endpoint)

Tags: java, mule, mulesoft

I have the mule config for http proxy as follows:

```
<pattern:http-proxy name="xxx-service-http-proxy">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="8589" />
</pattern:http-proxy>
```

now When I hit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html. I get the message

```
Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://localhost:8589swagger-ui.html
```

But when I hit http://localhost:8080//swagger-ui.html. Everything works as expected (**needs double slashes**). Can anyone point me out where I made a mistake.

The documentation from the Http proxy mentions nothing about that: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.5/http-proxy-pattern

Comment: I think these 'pattern' configurations are obsolete and should be replaced but combining the more modern HTTP Listener and Requester from newer versions of Mule. I don't advise relying on patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue arises as there is no base path at all to append to.

Try to add the explicit path parameter to the outbound:

```
<http:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="8589" path="/" />
```

Or use the URL style for the outbound:

```
<http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8589" />
```